# selected row in custom cell doesn't pass complete data from segue to another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
            self.data= [self.nameList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            self.data= [self.rollList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailVC" sender:self];
        }
```

I've displayed student's name and roll number in custom cell. Now when i select one row i would like to pass those data to another `UIViewController` and display in labels. For I've one `NSObject` type file called 'Name' and i've one variable called 'data' which is of type 'Name'. Now here's my code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` where the `nameList` is overlapped by `rollList` which are stored on same variable `self.data`. if `rollList` line is removed then it works good. But when I store `rollList` in `self.data` it will overlap other.

Where, `self.nameList` is variable of type `NSMutableArray` which contains name of student and similarly, `self.rollList` contains student's roll.

Below is the code to pass data from segue. Here `DetailVC` is the `destinationViewController`, `vc.data` is the variable of type 'Name' and `self.data` is also the variable of same type.

```
     -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
            if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailVC"]){
                DetailVC *vc = (DetailVC *) segue.destinationViewController;
                vc.data = self.data;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are overriding data to 'self.data', you might not be getting namelist I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Overlapping is fundamental thing.

In your case your in `NSObject type file (Name) you have to add two variable`

```
NSNumber *rollNo;
NSString *name;
```

After that

**-- UPDATE --**

```
@interface TableVC : UIViewController {   
    Name *data;
}
-(void)viewDidLoad {
      data = [[Name alloc] init]
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
            self.data.name = [self.nameList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            self.data.rollNo = [self.rollList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailVC" sender:self];
}
```

Then

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
            if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailVC"]){
                DetailVC *vc = (DetailVC *) segue.destinationViewController;
                vc.data = self.data;
            }
}
```

------ Detail VC ---

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Name *data;


-(void)viewDidLoad {
      self.labelRollNo.text = self.data.rollNo;
      self.labelName.text = self.data.name;
}
```

Comment: Obviously nil, because this will got assigned when you select one cell `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: print log in didSelectRowAtIndexPath after assigning  self.data.name = `[self.nameList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            self.data.rollNo = [self.rollList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; NSLog(@"Name: %@", self.data.name);`

Comment: Again its logging null

Comment: make sure you have wrote initialization code for your Name class like `Name *data = [[Name alloc] init]; ` and also make debug point in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`  and also check `self.nameList` and `self.rollList` have value at indexPath.row index

Comment: Name *data = [[Name alloc]init];
    self.data.name = [self.nameList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.data.roll= [self.rollList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", self.data.name); is this all right? But where should I use the variable data? And also, self.nameList and self.rollList is not carrying any data when i log it. it prints something like this: <Name: 0x7fcff3c1f330>",
    "<Name: 0x7fcff3f02970>",
    "<Name: 0x7fcff3f02990>"

Comment: I'm sorry to say, only such initialization on viewDidLoad is not working still.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/ may this forum help you

Comment: Without seeing your full code not possible what is problem actually. Please share it on github if possible

Comment: No, I want you to guide me few more, I've uploaded my project in Bitbucket and wand to share it with you. I need your email id to share I think. Can you give me your email id?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSString *name;
    NSString *roll;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        name= [self.nameList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        roll= [self.rollList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailVC" sender:self];
 }

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
       if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailVC"]){
            DetailVC *vc = (DetailVC *) segue.destinationViewController; 
            vc.name = name;
            vc.roll = roll;
        }
 }
```

you create two `NSString` name and roll properties in your DetailVC

DetailVC.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *roll;
```